# Counting numbers of Fixed point of Zeta function by Argument Principle

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, riemann-zeta, fixed-points

This is my first [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102336/fixed-point-of-riemann-zeta-function) about this topic and now I am trying to evaluate the integral,
$$N=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z-1|=1}\frac{\zeta'(z)-1}{\zeta(z)-z}dz+1$$
$\zeta-$is the Riemann Zeta function. I am expecting that $N=1$ i.e. the integration will be zero but I am unable to do so. Further, I have tried to check for $|z-1|=r$ for any suitable $r>0$ but nothing meaningful happened.

If my assumption is wrong or somehow there is any mistake in the integral [something with well definedness] kindly let me know.

Any help/guide/complete derivation will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z)  =\frac{\zeta'(z)-1}{\zeta(z)-z}$. It is the derivative of $\log (\zeta(z)-z)$ so you can approximate it numerically to find the branch of $\log (\zeta(z)-z)$ continuous on $1+e^{it},t\in (0,2\pi)$.

Otherwise with the residue theorem, if $\zeta(z) -z$ doesn't have any zero on $|z-1|\le 1$ then $z=1$ is the only pole of  inside $|z-1|<1$ and $$\int_{|z-1|=1} f(z)dz = 2i\pi Res(f(z),z=1)=-2i\pi$$ The residue is $-1$ because $\zeta(z)$ has a simple pole at $z=1$ so $\zeta(z) = \frac{C}{z-1}+O(1)$ and $$ f(z) = \frac{\frac{-C}{(z-1)^2}+O(1)}{\frac{C}{z-1}+O(1)} =\frac{-1}{z-1}+O(1)$$

Also you can do it without the residue theorem using that $\int_{|z-1|=r} f(z)dz$  doesn't depend on $r\le 1$ (Cauchy integral theorem) ie. $$\int_{|z-1|=1} f(z)dz = \lim_{r \to 0}\int_{|z-1|=r} f(z)dz= \lim_{r \to 0}\int_{|z-1|=r} \frac{-1}{z-1}dz+\int_{|z-1|=r}O(1)dz\\=\lim_{r \to 0} -2i\pi+O(r)=-2i\pi$$

Comment: I am having confusion with the line where you said *if $\zeta(z)-z$ has no fixed point in ...*. Why did you assumed that?

Comment: I didn't, I'm saying the number of zeros of $f(z)=\zeta(z)-z$ inside $|z-1|< r$ is the value of the integral you gave that we can find numerically (just plot $\log f(1+re^{it}) $ and count the number of discontinuities) plus the number of poles, which is known.