# Exact value for $~ x : \zeta(x) = x$

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

(For $~x~$ is real)

Wolfram alpha calculates this value to be approx $~1.83377265168...~$

But does anyone know of a method in which we could find an exact value for this?

Also, are there any other interesting properties of this number that is known?

This is for my own curiosity as during one of my maths lessons on series I pondered this question, too which my teacher couldn't answer. While i do believe that this value does have interesting properties which may be used in some fields of number theory, I myself cannot see an immediate application. However, this said, the methods that would be used to solve such a problem could be transferable to similar problems.

**Edit:** I refer to exact value meaning a value that uses one of the known and calculable mathematics constants (e.g., $\pi, e,$ Apéry's constant, ect.) or involving a function (such as sqrt ect.)

Comment: What is an "exact value"?

Comment: Also check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102336/fixed-point-of-riemann-zeta-function?noredirect=1

Comment: Last comment: Search for "dynamics of zeta function" and you'll find e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.08779.pdf and https://leeconjecture.wordpress.com/2015/02/12/a-dynamical-approach-to-riemann-zeta-function/ and https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/mark_pollicott/p3/warsaw-lectures-5may.pdf

Comment: When i say this I mean a value that uses one of the known and calculable mathematics constants (eg Pi, e, aperys constant, ect.) or involving a function (such as sqrt ect), sorry for the misunderstanding- will update question/ also thanks for the other link

Comment: Joe. I have done some works on that. Have a look at my asked question in my profile. You may find something useful.