Infinitely nested series
Just for fun, I decided to play around with sums and I did this: $$\sum_{n_{1}=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{n_{1}^{\sum_{n_{2}=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{n_{2}^{\sum_{n_{3}=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{n_{3}^{\sum_{n_{4}=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{n_{4}^{\sum_{n_{5}=1}^{∞}...}}}}}}}}$$
Simplifed version (simplified by Martin Brandenburg): $$s=\sum_{n=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{n^{s}}$$
I tried looking this up to see if it exists, and I tried different online calculators, but I couldn't find anything helpful, or anything that could possibly help me solve this. Is there anyone here who might know a way to either go about solving this, or at least can suggest things to try? Is this even possible?
Let me know if I gave enough information, and if not, I'll update the question as soon as I can :)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Basically, you are asking if there is some positive real number $s$ with $s=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {1/n^s}$.

Yes. I like the way that you simplified that. I don't know how I didn't think of that before. I'll edit the original post and credit you with the simplified version.

This might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102336/fixed-point-of-riemann-zeta-function

Yeah, that helped me!

If your problem is to solve for $s$ the equation $$s=\sum_{n=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{n^{s}}=\zeta(s)$$ you know that $s<2$.
Expanded around $s=2$
$$\zeta(s)=\frac {\pi^2} 6\Bigg(1+\left(\gamma+\log \left(\frac{2 \pi}{A^{12}}\right) \right) (s-2)   \Bigg)+O((s-2)^2)$$ where $A$ is Glaisher constant.
The series being truncated at this level, converted to decimal
$$s=1.81674$$ while the "exact" solution given by Newton method is $\color{red}{1.83377}$.
You could have another approximation around $s=2$
$$\zeta(s)=\frac {\pi^2} 6+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\zeta^{(n)}(s) }{n! }(s-2)^n$$ with, as before
$$\zeta^{(1)}(s) =\frac {\pi^2} 6 \left(\gamma+\log \left(\frac{2 \pi}{A^{12}}\right)\right)=\color{red}{k} $$ and notice that, $\forall n>1$
$$\frac {\zeta^{(n)}(2) }{n! } \sim (-1)^n$$
Using this approximation, the equation becomes
$$s=\frac {\pi^2} 6+k\,(s-2)+\frac{(s-2)^2}{s-1}$$ which reduces to a quadratic
$$6 k s^2-\left(18 k+18-\pi ^2\right)s+\left(12 k-\pi   ^2+24\right)=0$$ the solution of which being $\color{red}{1.83383}$.
